# What are the reasons behing the same origin policy in Ajax?

Tags: ajax, same-origin-policy

Why was this policy even created? Seems to me that there are only disadvantages of this. If you want to, there are ways to access another domain (for example, JSONP). Wouldn't it be much easier for everybody if there was no such policy?
But I suppose that the guys who created it are smart and that they did it for a reason. I'd like to know this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security.

If it didn't exist, and your site accepted input from a user, I could do bad things.  For example, I could put some javascript in the text I entered on your site, that did an ajax call to my domain.      When anyone viewed my input (like on SO, when we view your question), that javascript would execute.  I could look at how your website worked in my inspector, add observers to your input, and steal your users' data.

The same origin policy prevents me from sending your data to my domain via ajax.  To see how easy it is, if you have a simple website, just put the following in one of your forms and submit the data.

`javascript:alert(document.cookie);`

If you don't take steps to do something about that (your framework might automatically), I just injected javascript into your site, and when someone views it it will execute.  (It's called **javascript injection**)

Now imagine I got a little more creative and added some ajax code....

The browser *needs* to prevent such things or using the web would be digital suicide.

Comment: This seems like a pretty shallow answer.  Are you going to be expanding on it?

Comment: its a pretty basic question.  i provided a basic answer.  if you think more should go in, please let me know.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, can't injected javascript code do something bad using existing hacks for cross-domain requests, such as JSONP?

Comment: jsonp can only retrieve, not POST.  ajax is only a small part of cross site scripting.  Same Origin Policy is a first line of defense.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, but with JSONP you can send parameters with GET. And with big number of requests you can send a pretty big amount of information.

Comment: sergey thats true. same origin policy is not a catch-all for security concerns.  It is one layer, a first line of defense.  You can get around the same origin policy also by injecting an iframe into a page.

Comment: This is wrong. You are describing a XSS attack and the same origin policy doesn't prevent that all all. If you can execute JS on a third party site then nothing stops you sending data gathered there elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Same Origin Policy is **not** primarily meant to defend against **Cross Site Scripting** (XSS) as stated above but to hinder **Cross Site Request Forgery** (CSRF).

A malicious site shall not be able to load data from other sites unless this is allowed by that other host explicitly.

E.g. When I browse www.malicious.com I would not want it to be able to access my concurrent authenticated session at www.mybank.com, request some of my data from the bank's AJAX interface and send it to malicious.com using my browser as relay.

To bypass this restriction for intended use or public information the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) protocol has been implemented in modern browsers.

Comment: What if cross-site requests were allowed but browser would not send any session data in such case? Malicious.com could've access mybank.com in the same way anyone can access it!